# Is the subset of compactly supported functions a linear subspace of $C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

I have been ask to provide justification if the subset of compactly supported functions is a linear subspace of $C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ and have no real idea of where to start. Could someone please give me some direction as to how to start and proceed here?

Edit: My proof would go as follows.

1. The set of compactly supported functions is non empty as all bump functions are compactly supported.
2. We also have closure under addition: take $f$ and $g$ as two compactly supported functions. Then by the triangle inequality
   Supp(f+g) $\leq$ Supp(f) + Supp (g). We know that Supp(f) and Supp(g) are compact and all subsets of compact sets are also compact, hence Supp(f+g) is compact, so we satisfy closure under addition.
3. Take any compactly supported function $f$ and let $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then Supp($a\dot f$)=a Supp($f$) which is also compactly supported, hence we have closure under scalar multiplication.

Hence the subset of compactly supported functions is a linear subspace of $C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$.

Does this seem correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: Can you compare $\operatorname{supp}(f+g)$ with something related to $\operatorname{supp}(f)$ and $\operatorname{supp}(g)$?

Comment: What is the definition of a set being a linear subspace?

Comment: Is the sum of compactly supported functions compactly supported? Is a multipl of a compactly supported function compactly supported. Please at least try the basics.

Comment: Well we have the set is non empty as any bump function is compactly supported. Also the set is closed under scalar multiplication as the output of the function is just multiplied by the scalar. It is the closure under addition that I have struggled with